# ADMIN LOGIN falla en la linea de AUTH::

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario de login para admin pero me arroja el error siguiente:

Compre un curso de laravel pero al parecer hay mucha informacion que está desactualizada, apesar de que en el curso están usando laravel 5.2 (me parece) y yo 5.8. Pero no se si sea esta la razón de que el código esta mal... ya que estoy poniendo exactamente el mismo codigo... Lo mismo me sucede al enviar correos pero ya les preguntaré eso más adelante.

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_PARSE) syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Aqui se encuentran mis archivos:

AdminUserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminUserController extends Controller

    public function store(Request $request){

            $request->validate([
                'email', 'required|email',
                'password', 'required'
            ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password')

        if (! Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return back()->withErrors([
                'message' => 'Datos incorrectos, Intenta nuevamente.'
            ]);
        }

        session()->flash('msg','Has iniciado sesión.');

        // Redirect
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
}
```

auth.php

```
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

    ],

    'providers' => [

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\AdminUser::class,
        ],

    ],
```

**adminUser.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;


class AdminUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si estas usando `LAravel 5.8` no hay necesidad de configurar tanto, ni los errores

1.- crea tu proyecto nuevo.

2.- Escribe el siguiente comando.

> php artisan make:auth
>
> php artisan migrate

y ya tienes todo respecto al `Login` y `Registro`

- validacion de campos vacios
- validacion de correos únicos
- manejo de `Session`
- Usuario y contraseña incorrecta.

Usalo y continua con tu curso

> Nota: Actualiza tus credenciales de la `DB` antes de usar los comandos

Answer (score 0):

El error puede que este en la estructura del if, los {} te estan causando problemas.

```
  if(blabla)
   return ...
  else
   return ...

 public function store(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'email', 'required|email',
            'password', 'required',
        ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password')

    if (! Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) 
        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => 'Datos incorrectos, Intenta nuevamente.'
        ],401);


    session()->flash('msg','Has iniciado sesión.');

    // Redirect
    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Le falta el punto y coma a esta linea:

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password')
```